# Circular crop: extract non rectangular parts of an image

Tags: image-processing

I want to extract a part of an image. For example, let's start with something like the following image:

[image]

I would like to apply some image processing to get this result:

[image]

I have tried to manipulate `Graphics[Disk]` and the image using `ImageAdd` but it looks like the `Graphics[Disk]` is a box that contains a disk, so adding the *Mathematica* logo image to the `Disk` outputs a white box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
extractAnnulus[image_, {r1_, r2_}] := Module[{mask},
  mask = Rasterize[Graphics[
     {White, Disk[{0, 0}, r2], Black, Disk[{0, 0}, r1]},
     PlotRange -> 1,
     Background -> Black,
     ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[image]
     ],
    ImageResolution -> 72 (* Necessary as of Mathematica 12.1 *)
    ];
  ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[image, mask], ColorNegate[mask]]
  ]

img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/paxJ9.png"];
extractAnnulus[img, {0.4, 0.6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: excellent!! Thank you so much.

Comment: BTW, I was initially confused, but looks like your r1 and r2 are a %age of the image size..right?

Comment: @JMarc Yes, I set `PlotRange` to one which means that zero is the top/left edges of the mask (a graphics object), and 1 is the bottom/right edges of the mask. i.e. I create a coordinate system where all coordinates are between 0 and 1. Then I specify, using `ImageSize`, that the corresponding image of this graphics object should have the same size as the image we are putting the mask over. This is actually useful to understand, because this approach breaks if the aspect ratio of the image is not square, then the aspect ratio has to be taken into account when creating the mask.

Comment: Does not work for me in 12.1. There is an additional black ring.

Comment: @Natas Thank you for notifying me about this. I don't know yet why the example in my original answer cannot be reproduced but I have now provided a work-around.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks for providing the work-around. Seems like a bug in the option `ImageSize`.

Comment: @Natas I made a new update, solving the issue by setting `ImageResolution`. Kirkus and Rohit figure it out [in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55243842#55243842). The issue had been previously mentioend [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219227/731).

Comment: @C.E. Thanks for the info. Frankly, I am quite upset that this is not explained in the documentation of `ImageSize`. This is not the behavior an "ordinary" user would expect.