# Creating a graph with scaled, circular images replacing each vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image

I'd like to create a graph where the vertices are replaced by scaled versions of images, with the images fitting in the circles (like the avatar [here](https://media.creativemornings.com/uploads/user/avatar/135719/circular_DC.png)).

My attempt at this graph simply overlays the flags, creating a very ugly outcome:[image]

Here's the code sample that generated the graph above.

```
v1 = {"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"};
vSize1 = {1, 3, 0.3};
vSizeRule1 = Transpose@{v1, vSize1} /. List[a_, b_] -> Rule[a, b];
m1 = {{∞, 1, 1}, {1, ∞, 
    1}, {1, ∞, ∞}};
vShapeRule1 = 
 Flatten[# -> Placed[CountryData[#, "Flag"], Center] & /@ v1]
g1 = Graph[
  WeightedAdjacencyGraph[v1, m1],
  VertexLabels -> vShapeRule1,
  VertexSize -> vSizeRule
  ]
```

How can I do better without downloading circular avatars and scaling them by hand?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/circular-crop-extract-non-rectangular-parts-of-an-image

Comment: I do not have time to update my answer, but here's what can be improved if you want to set different vertex sizes for each vertex and maintain a good appearance: instead of `VertexShape`, use a `VertexShapeFunction` that returns the appropriate shape for each vertex.  The sizes should still be set through `VertexSize`.  Finally, add `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`.  I am not sure it will work, but it is what I would try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use [`VertexShape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexShape.html), and create a [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html)d polygon for each country.

---

```
v1 = {"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"};

disk = {EdgeForm[Black], 
   Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> #] &@
    CirclePoints[{1/2, 1/2}, 1/2, 25]};

vertexShapes = 
 Graphics@{Texture@Image@CountryData[#, "Flag"], disk} & /@ v1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, this needs some improvement.  In particular, the aspect ratio of the flags should be less distorted. That is a bit difficult because this differs from flag to flag.

```
VertexReplace[
 CompleteGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexShape -> Thread[Range[3] -> vertexShapes], VertexSize -> 0.3, 
  EdgeStyle -> Gray],
 Thread[Range[3] -> v1]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**

```
v1 = {"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"};

disk = {EdgeForm[Black], 
   Polygon[CirclePoints[30], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> CirclePoints[{1/2, 1/2}, 1/2, 30]]};

vertexShapes = 
 Graphics@{Texture@
      Rasterize[CountryData[#, "Flag"], "Image", ImageSize -> 200], 
     disk} & /@ v1

shapes = AssociationThread[v1, vertexShapes]

shapeFun[pt_, v_, sz_] := Translate[Scale[First@shapes[v], sz], pt]

g = VertexReplace[
  CompleteGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True],
  Thread[Range[3] -> v1]
  ]

Graph[g, VertexShapeFunction -> shapeFun, 
 VertexSize -> Thread[v1 -> {.2, .4, .3}], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", EdgeStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

Key points:

For correct arrowhead positioning with scaled vertices, we need to add `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`, and we need to specify the vertex shapes as graphics primitives.  `VertexShape` uses an `Inset` under the hood, which prevents the system from detecting the shape of the vertex and placing the arrowheads at the right place.  It will treat the vertices as rectangles.  To work around this, we needed to use `VertexShapeFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possibilities. Both are improvements over what you show, The 1st one makes square flags just fill the vertex circles; the 2nd makes the flags just fill the vertex circles, but maintains their aspect ratios.

#### Countries

```
countries = {"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"};
```

#### Square flags

```
ShapeRule1 = 
  # -> 
    Placed[
      Show[CountryData[#, "Flag"], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 70.7], 
      Center] & /@ countries;

Graph[
  WeightedAdjacencyGraph[countries, {{∞, 1, 1}, {1, ∞, 1}, {1, ∞, ∞}}],
  VertexLabels -> ShapeRule1,
  VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image: graph1]

#### Flags with preserved aspect ratios

```
flagSize[aspectRatio_] :=
  Module[{n = Numerator[aspectRatio], d = Denominator[aspectRatio]},
    100. d/Norm[{n, d}]]

ShapeRule2 =
  # ->
     Placed[
       Show[CountryData[#, "Flag"], 
         ImageSize -> flagSize[ImageAspectRatio[CountryData[#, "Flag"]]]], 
       Center] & /@ countries;

Graph[
  WeightedAdjacencyGraph[countries, {{∞, 1, 1}, {1, ∞, 1}, {1, ∞, ∞}}],
  VertexLabels -> ShapeRule2,
  VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image: graph2]

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
cs = {"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium"};
imageResize[image_] := ImageResize[image, {128, 96}];
shapeRule = Rule[#, imageResize@CountryData[#, "Flag"]] & /@ cs;
m1 = {{\[Infinity], 1, 1}, {1, \[Infinity], 
   1}, {1, \[Infinity], \[Infinity]}}
g1 = Graph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[v1, m1], VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexShape -> shapeRule]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]