# Unexpected behaviour of ImageSize and ImageDimensions in 12.1

Tags: graphics, rasterize

Since upgrading to 12.1, I'm getting the following unexpected doubling of image sizes set with ImageSize and reported by ImageDimensions, as seen in the following MWE:

```
wi=200;
hi=100;
g1=Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize->{UpTo[wi],UpTo[hi]}];
g1 //ImageDimensions
g2=Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize->{wi,hi}];
g2//ImageDimensions
g3=Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize->{200,100}]; 
g3//ImageDimensions
```

produces the output:

```
{200, 200}
{400, 200}
{400, 200}
```

This does not happen in v.11.1 or 12.0. Is there a logical explanation?

Comment: Why I get different result from you?  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w6tRo.png)

Comment: see Szabolcs' answer below: I guess you have a different screen resolution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that when you apply `ImageDimensions`, or any other image-processing function to `Graphics`, the `Graphics` will be automatically `Rasterize`d to an `Image`. What you see is a change that was made to the default rasterization resolution.

---

Version 12.1 fully supports HiDPI, so some things are rendered at double resolution.

They made the decision to choose the resolution based on what screen you have connected to your computer. Hi-res screen: high resolution. Low-res screen: low resolution. I find this very irritating because the resolution will change by just plugging in a screen.

---

What you want to change is not the `ImageSize`, but the `ImageResolution`. "Normal" resolution is 72, and double resolution is `2*72 = 144`.

The default value should be [`$ImageResolution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ImageResolution.html). Thus, if you want to revert to the old behaviour, then do

```
Unprotect[$ImageResolution]
    $ImageResolution = 72;
```

Why `$ImageResolution` is `Protected`, even though it is *meant* to be set, I do not understand.

You can also use `ImageResolution -> 72` in functions like `Export` or `Rasterize`.

Note that this will not affect the behaviour of some GUI actions. Edit -> Copy As -> Bitmap will copy at the primary screen's resolution, no matter what you set for `$ImageResolution`. This is why you may see so many pasted over-sized graphics from me on this site recently. In the past, I used to use Edit -> Copy As -> Bitmap to get a standard-resolution image even when using a high-res screen.

Comment: All clear, thanks! I've just checked that it affects Export as well, so I need to adjust a lot of all scripts. Very irritating indeed...

Comment: @MichaelL. I think that putting `$ImageResolution = 72` at the beginning of all your notebooks/scripts should be sufficient (but do check the output carefully).

Comment: It is even more strange: Export works, but the only way to find out the actual image size seems to be Export and Import: `Unprotect[$ImageResolution];
$ImageResolution = 72;
g3 = Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]; 
g3 // ImageDimensions
Export["g3.jpg", g3]
g4 = Import["g3.jpg"];
g4 // ImageDimensions`