# What does Global Magnification actually do?

Tags: export, formatting

In preferences (at least in mathematica 12.0+), there is an option called "Global Magnification". At first glance, this option seems to scale the size of the text in notebooks (e.g. 75% makes things smaller, 115% makes things bigger). But it in fact does quite a bit more. It will affect the dimensions of plots when using options like ImageSize [(I learned this in my last question)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229973/mathematica-12-1-0-0-exporting-low-quality-images-at-high-imageresolution). At 75% Global Magnification, ImageSize->240 produces a 2.5 inch image. At 100% Global Magnification, ImageSize->240 produces a 3.33 inch image. Note, this later case is what you would expect from the documentation of ImageSize. The documentation states ImageSize works at 72 dots per inch. So 240 dots / (72 dots per inch) = 3.33 inches. It does note that 72 dots per inch is before magnification. So the different size images does make sense.

[Further reading shows setting the default text size in mathematica is a different procedure.](https://support.wolfram.com/25214?src=mathematica) But a layman (me) probably wouldn't know better.

So my question is what is Global Magnification really doing? What else does it change? And why might it be implemented in this way?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike other document editors, `Magnification` is a content attribute.  Normally, it is only set at the document level (so everything scales uniformly).  It can, however, be set at a more localized level via `Style`.  For instance, `Row[{"aa", Style["bb", Magnification -> 4], "cc"}]`.  When the setting in the Preferences dialog is changed, it is like adding `Magnification->0.75` to everything you do, thanks to inheritance.