# Why do the points in a curve are connected to those in another after FindClusters?

Tags: plotting, cluster-analysis

I have a few questions about the function `FindClusters`. There's two group points data, and the following figures are obtained from these data.

Figure 1-1 is the the `ListPlot` of the first group, and Figure 1-2 is its `ListLinePlot` after `FindClusters`. Figure 1-1 tell us that the first group data can generate 5 smooth curves, but why Figure 1-2 present an unexpected result? Why do the points belonged to a line are connected to those in another curve?

Figure 2-1 shows that we can get 3 curves from the second group data. But, in Figure 2-2, the first two curves are joined to one curve. The distance between two points in the second curve is close, why don't they joint together? The distance in the first two is far, but they are joined together. Why does it produce such a result? How to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Mathematica Version 12.3

**Full Codes**: Click [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyjfwknfdgp3vfe/TwoGroup.zip?dl=0) to download.
**An excerpt** of the codes:

```
trData={};
tiData={};

(*figure 1-1, 1-2*)
ListPlot[trData,AspectRatio->5/7,ImageSize->Medium]
trg=FindClusters[trData,5,Method-> "SpanningTree"];
ListLinePlot[trg,AspectRatio->5/7,ImageSize->Medium]

(*figure 2-1, 2-2*)
ListPlot[tiData, AspectRatio -> 5/7, ImageSize -> Medium]
tig = FindClusters[tiData, 5, Method -> "SpanningTree"];
ListLinePlot[tiData, AspectRatio -> 5/7, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Figure 1-1

[image]

Figure 1-2

[image]

Figure 2-1

[image]

Figure 2-2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot[trData, AspectRatio -> 5/7, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
trg1 = FindClusters[trData, 5, Method -> "SpanningTree",
   DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
```

The partition was for **at most** 5 clusters.

```
Length@trg1

(* 4 *)

ListLinePlot[trg1, AspectRatio -> 5/7, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

The third cluster needs to be split into two clusters

```
trg2 = (Sort /@ FindClusters[trg1[[3]], 2, Method -> "SpanningTree",
      DistanceFunction -> 
       ChessboardDistance]) //. (({start___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, 
        rest___} /; y2 - y1 > 1) :>
     {start, {x1, y1}, rest});

ListLinePlot[trg2, AspectRatio -> 5/7, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

The result is then

```
ListLinePlot[Join[trg1[[{1, 2, 4}]], trg2]]
```

[image]

The second data set is more straightforward.

```
ListPlot[tiData, AspectRatio -> 5/7, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
tig = FindClusters[tiData, 3, Method -> "SpanningTree",
   DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];

ListLinePlot[tig, AspectRatio -> 5/7, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have the following questions to ask you. **1.** Why is it not smooth enough near the start of the second curve in Figure 1-2? It seems that there are many points crisscross together, becomes very thick near there. **2.** The points inside the third curve should be closer in Figure 1-2, Why do they connect to the fourth curve. **3.** Why does the function `ChessboardDistance` is used? Why not use other functions? What are the selection criteria? **4.** Besides this function `FindClusters`, is there any other function that can deal with this problem better?

Comment: 1.) The points in the data are not ordered in a way to produce a smooth curve. 2.) I don't know; that is what came out of the algorithm. 3.) `ChessboardDistance` was a `DistanceFunction` used as an example in the documentation, it worked reasonably well, so I stopped looking. Experiment with other functions and use the one that best meets your needs. 4.) I don't know. Your question was specifically about `FindClusters`.